# How to configure the developer_certificate_path and developer_certificate_password with Forge

Tags: ios, trigger.io, forge

In the forge documentation it states:

> You should now be able to configure the `developer_certificate_path` and `developer_certificate_password` in your `local_config.json` file.

However, there are no examples of this or how to specify the provisioning profile.

Does anyone have any examples of the `local_config.json` file?

I have the path/file, password and provisioning profile - I just dont know this is formatted/used within the config file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, if you had the certificate saved as `my_certificate.pfx` in your current directory:

```
{
    "ios": {
        "profiles": {
            "DEFAULT": {
                "provisioning_profile": "development.mobileprovision",
                "developer_certificate_path": "my_certificate.pfx",
                "developer_certificate_password": "my password"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'll improve coverage of this in our documentation too: thanks for the heads up! For now, there's a mention here: http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.3/tools/local-config.html#format-of-local-config-json

Comment: I ran "forge package ios" and its says my provisioning profile and application id do not match; from the profile it displays, it appears the provisioning profile is wrong. (.io.trigger... - instead of myprofile.mobileprovision). Any ideas?

Comment: Rolled into separate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11073631/provisioning-profile-and-application-id-do-not-match-why