# Provisioning Profile and application Id do not match, why?

Tags: trigger.io, forge

When I run **forge run ios** , I get this:

> [  ERROR] Provisioning profile and application ID do not match 
>   Provisioning profile ID:
>   G85A58Y2F3.io.trigger.forge4afef416b8a111e1910212313d1 adcbe 
>   Application ID: G85A58Y2F3.co.uk.nearbyapp.*  Please see "Preparing
>   your apps for app stores" in our docs:
>   http://current-docs.trigger.io/releasing.html#ios

My local config looks like this

```
{
    "general": {
    },"ios": {
        "device": "device",
        "profiles": {
            "DEFAULT": {
                "provisioning_profile": "nearby.mobileprovision",
                "developer_certificate_path": "nearby_certificate.pfx",
                "developer_certificate_password": "xxxxx"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas of what could be wrong? I don't understand where the trigger provision id is coming from.

*Edit*: Ok , I changed the provisioning profile to be a wildcard one - I assume this is needed for running on the device? anyway, that resolved the error I was getting. Now, I get quite a bit further...

It seems to install on the device but I get this in the command window:

> Launching -
>   /private/var/mobile/Applications/ABBD210F-2683-46D0-BAF2-ED2AC25279A
>   4/device-ios.app Could not start com.apple.debugserver!

The app doesnt start automatically but it is installed on the device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To give a bit more information on the original question: Trigger automatically generate an app ID if one is not specified. You can then either use that app ID when creating provisioning profiles, etc., or you can override the app ID with an existing value.

I've updated our documentation to be more explicit here - it was a bit unclear before! http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.3/modules/package_names.html

For your follow-on question, we've not quite handled running the app automatically on iOS from Windows: we're hoping to add that soon, in a future sprint.

Comment: Thanks for this. I guess when you run "forge run ios" and you are on windows it would be a better experience to not even try to run the app.. so no error is displayed.